# Inverse law Vs Complementary law

Tags: boolean-algebra

I being confused with

**A + A̅ = 1  / A . A̅ = 0** law.

What is this law? Is this *Complementary law* or *Inverse law* or other law?

Answer (score 0):

In fact some sources classify the above laws as Complementary law, and some others as the Inverse law but both are acceptable.

Comment: so thats mean i can use both names for express the laws. right?

Comment: @BachiNirosh Yes, you are right.